# Ratio test and radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to find the radius of convergence for:

$$\sum \ln j^3 x^j$$

By the ratio test, I get:

$$\displaystyle\frac{\ln (j+1)^3 x^{j+1}}{\ln j^3x^j}$$

However, I'm not sure what happens to the ln parts in terms of convergence?

Comment: The limit test applied should give:$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left|\displaystyle\frac{\ln (j+1)^3 x^{j+1}}{\ln j^3x^j}\right|$$Not$$\displaystyle\frac{\ln (j+1)^3 x^{j+1}}{\ln j^3x^j}$$

Comment: Yes, I know, I just wrote out the inside ratio and I am having trouble finding the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left|\displaystyle\frac{\ln (j+1)^3 x^{j+1}}{\ln j^3x^j}\right|=|x|\lim_{j\to\infty}\left|\displaystyle\frac{\ln (j+1) }{\ln j}\right|=|x|<1$$
Use L'Hopital's for the last step.

Comment: Quick question, how did the cubic go away?

Comment: @kiwifruit Basic logarithms: $$\ln(x^b)=b\ln x$$